# How can i change the position of new Label after pressing enter in Text Input?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In this program i specified in `enter` function the position of new label after pressing enter in `Text Input` but it is not working.

```
def enter(self):
     nl=Label(text='2',pos_hint={'x':0,'y':.06})
     self.box.add_widget(nl)
```

I can not control the position of that `Label`.

[image]

How can i fix this problem?

code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

 

Builder.load_string("""


<Box>
    t1:t1
    l1:l1
    box:box
    BoxLayout:
        id:box
        size: root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:l1
            pos_hint:{'x':0,'y':0}
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: 33
            width: 100
            text:'1'
            background_color: 6/255, 61/255, 81/255, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        TextInput:
            id:t1
            on_text_validate:root.enter()
            cursor_color: 255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8 
            pos_hint:{'x':.1,'y':0}
            multiline:False
            height: 33
            width:800
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            foreground_color: 255/255, 167/255, 167/255, 0.51













""")

class Box(Widget):
    t1=ObjectProperty(None)
    l1=ObjectProperty(None)
    box=ObjectProperty(None)
    def enter(self):
         nl=Label(text='2',pos_hint={'x':0,'y':.06})
         self.box.add_widget(nl)
         


class foo(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor='#1618388'
       
        return Box()







if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your label l1 is covering your TextInput.
So you either need to delete it, move it in the under text input or move the position of it.

here is what I mean with under textinput:

```
<Box>
    t1:t1
    l1:l1
    box:box
    BoxLayout:
        id:box
        size: root.width,root.height
        TextInput:
            id:t1
            on_text_validate: root.enter()
            cursor_color: 255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8 
            pos_hint: {'x':.1,'y':0}
            multiline: False
            height: 33
            width:800
            size_hint: None, None
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            foreground_color: 255/255, 167/255, 167/255, 0.51
        Label:
            id:l1
            pos_hint:{'x':0,'y':0}
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: 33
            width: 100
            text:'1'
            background_color: 6/255, 61/255, 81/255, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
```

Then the textinput will overlay the Label you would not be able to see the label.